# Plot sine waves over world map in Python

Tags: python, plot, trigonometry

I need to plot some sine waves over a projected mercator world map. These waves are nothing but the orbits of some satellites I'm working with. For the projected map I use the following:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-180.,llcrnrlat=-60.,urcrnrlon=180.,urcrnrlat=60.,
                rsphere=(6378137.00,6356752.3142),
                resolution='l',projection='merc',
                lat_0=40.,lon_0=-20.,lat_ts=20.)
world.drawcoastlines()
world.fillcontinents()
world.drawparallels(np.arange(-60,60,15),labels=[1,1,0,1])
world.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,45),labels=[1,1,0,1])

plt.show()
```

but have no idea how to overplot a sine wave, with a custom amplitude and period.

Comment: Better draw a projection of the actual orbit, it may not be an exact sine wave.

Comment: The "great circle between NY and London" from the [Basemap examples page](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html) could be a good starting point.

Comment: Yeah, I already looked at that, but it uses a particular method called drawgreatcircle() and I don't find another method for overplotting custom functions...

Comment: I don't have orbital data and I don't need very precise measures. I just need to plot a qualitatively picture of satellite projected orbits on the planisphere to enhance some latitudinal shifts